# Change text language in HTML pages from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localization, translation

I have a JavaScript file where I need to create some kind of dictionary (containing translated text) from a html page, and to be able to change language from the HTML header.

```
<a class="text-center" id='lnkHumanResources'>
        <p><img width="100" height="100" src="assets/img/icons/home-hr.png" /></p>
        <h1>Ljudski resursi</h1>
    </a>
```

This is an example of code containing the string which needs to be translated

"Ljudski resursi" to "Human Resources".

So, I need to have some hard - coded text on different languages in .js file, and some kind of method to change language from HTML header, and include it to few HTML pages that need to be able to change language.

---

***Solved***

Whoever gets stuck with same kind of problem, see [Translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/)

Download plugin and unzip it into your lib folder, and include it to all html pages you want to translate

```
<script src="assets/js/lib/translate.js-master/jquery.translate.js"></script>
```

I also created **dictionary.js** containing all strings I wanted to translate from all pages on few languages, and included it also to all html pages that needed to be translated

```
var dict = {      // dictionary.js
  "Home": {
    pt: "Início",
    en: "Home"
  },
  "Download plugin": {
    pt: "Descarregar plugin",
    en: "Download plugin"
  }
};
```

Include to html example:

```
<script src="assets/js/lib/dictionary.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to wrap all hard coded strings with span attribute with class "trn"

```
<p class="some-class"><span class="trn">Text to translate</span></p>
```

Then just add next line in html pages and you're good to go :)

```
var translator = $('body').translate({lang: "en", t: dict}); // en to use English
```

Comment: so what so called field to u work ??

Comment: check this out -> https://www.i18next.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text` function of jquery to change the content of the `h1`

```
  $('#lnkHumanResources h1').text("Human Resources");
```

dont forget to link the JQuery to your Html page

Comment: I see you are front end developer, with good knowledge of JavaScript and JQuery. Can you please provide some more details how to assign that translated text as "en" (english) and connect it to html header so it can be changeable

Comment: you cannot connect it to the Html  need to add an event listener like a click , so when the user click on a certain button its translate the text